# How to prevent public access to a website

Tags: wordpress, shared-hosting

I have accessed websites before where I need to put in an IP address and url into a host file and this is the only way to access it. If you don't put the details into a [host file](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/modifying-your-hosts-file/) and visit the url, you won't see the website. By how do I actually make my website behave in this way in that it is not accessible without using the host file? I have a wordpress site on shared hosting.

Comment: Do you want to access your website in remote hosting with the not real domain name? or you have a domain and what be accessible for you only?

Comment: I have a domain name with a website on it. It is under development but I need to test it. I don't want to use a coming soon page, I just want it to be like the site doesn't exist unless I put the IP address and domain name into a host file on my computer so only I can access the domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin [restricted site access](https://10up.com/plugins/restricted-site-access-wordpress/). It will allow you to change your ip after login and show a message to other ip address users until the website is in development.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .htaccess to limit access only from your [public internet IP](https://whatismyipaddress.com/):

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from yourip
```

or use [.htaccess Authentication](https://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/)

Comment: Thanks. This would work if I had a static IP address which I don't. I will have to update the IP address constantly.

Comment: @user10980228 use basic HTTP Authentication I add above.